# Keeping array of ImageIcon or BufferedImage?

Tags: java, swing, type-conversion, bufferedimage, imageicon

My Java program loads a bunch of image on startup. For now for each image I call this piece of code. Eventually I get an array of ImageIcon, which would be used in user interface.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(imagePath);
bimage = ImageIO.read(is);
is.close();
Image img = bimage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
return new ImageIcon(img);
```

But now I want to implement a method which would get an object from array and add title in specified language. So I have to use Graphics2D.drawString(). But ImageIcon does not have createGraphics() method. Is there a way I can get Graphics from ImageIcon?

```
Graphics2D g = bimage.createGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.setFont(new Font( "SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25 ));
g.drawString("TEST", 25, 25);
```

Now is the question: **should I keep array of ImageIcon or BufferedImage?**

Comment: Do you add these texts once or do you change the texts? How often do you change if you do?

Comment: Personally, I'd keep the reference to BufferedImage, this is purely from the point of view of some one who does a lot of heavy grahhics work, so I find the BufferedImage more flexible to work with. Having said that, there s nothing you are doing that couldn't be accomplished with an ImageIcon

Comment: @TobiasRitzau I don't change it once. It keeps changing all the time in this task.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yeah, it can be done using both ways and appropriate conversions. It is a matter of taste and maybe efficiency, or even something else.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I'd argue that because you're reading the images in as BufferedImages, that wrapping them in ImageIcon is an additional step you don't need. Also, if you are drawing to the images, I'd make a copy first, so the original is not tinted

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov maybe important for why reason(s), whats goal, maybe not ...

Comment: @mKorbel, no idea about what you are meaning :)

Comment: whats real reason for image with caption

Comment: @mKorbel, I develop a board game. There cards have some image and title. To support multiple languages title should be changable.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, how about scaling? I will get the images from array a great number of times. If I keep it like BufferedImage then I have to scaling every time I get image and before adding title.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I have tried to scale from BufferedImage to BufferedImage "bimage = (BufferedImage)bimage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);" but it raises an exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage"

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov board_game where these elements could be react to Mouse and Keyboard event or ???

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov There are many techniques you can use for scaling the images.  If you know the images are always going to be static size you scale them before they are loaded and save you're self the trouble.  You should have a read of [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html), it presents some interesting ideas, one of more common approaches I see regularly is the divide and conquer approach, where you scale the image by 50% (or divide by 2) until you reach the desired size. This doesn't require `Image`

Comment: Another solution that may be simpler is to place a text label on top of the image.

Comment: @TobiasRitzau, yes it might be another solution, but position of that JLabel would be a nightmare.